# Iterating through textboxes using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am building a page with asp.net. I have a form with a table that contains TextBoxes and a submit button. When the form is submitted, I want to grab all the text that was entered into the TextBoxes and operate on them. To do this, I have the following method:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        if (c.GetType().Name == "TextBox")
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)c;
            sb.AppendLine(tb.Text);
        }
    }
    Label1.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

The problem with this is that the controls apparently doesn't include any of my textboxes. When I iterate through the controls and print out their names, the only one I get is "site_master." (I also tried Controls and Page.Controls instead of this.Controls).

Is there something wrong with my iterator? Is there another way in which I could iterate through all of the textboxes in the table or page? What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Try `this.Form.Controls`. Your textboxes are basically nested in another container, you need to query the controls of that container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would it be too much to build a `List<Textbox>`, given you know all your textbox controls?

```
List<Textbox> txtBoxes = new List<Textbox>();
txtBoxes.Add(tb1);
txtBoxes.Add(tb2);
//etc..
```

Then you have a nice list to work with

Answer (score 2):

If I knew the controls were all in a given containing control, I would simply poll the controls of *that* control. For example, `this.Form.Controls`. However, if they could be nested within other child controls, then you could recursively explore the depths from a common outer container.

```
private IEnumerable<T> FindControls<T>(Control parent) where T : Control
{
    foreach (Control control in parent.Controls)
    {
        if (control is T)
            yield return (T)control;

        foreach (T item in FindControls<T>(control))
            yield return item;
    }
}
```

So this would allow you to retrieve all `TextBox` children.

```
List<TextBox> textBoxes = this.FindControls<TextBox>(this).ToList();
string output = string.Join(",", textBoxes.Select(tb => tb.Text));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you are using web forms ASP.NET.  Typically you declare your controls on the aspx page using something similar to

```
<asp:TextBox ID="someId" runat="server/>
```

If you have done this then in your code behind your should just be able to reference the variable `someId` and the property `Text` to get/set the text in the control.

If you are building the controls dynamically on the server you should be able to stick them in a list and iterate through it.  Make sure you are creating the controls and adding them to the table during the correct part of the [page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).  When you add them to a cell in the table you could also keep a reference to the control in a list and just enumerate through that list in your event handler.

Maybe something along the lines of (I didn't compile this so there are probably issues):

```
public class MyPage: Page
{
  private List<TextBox> TxtBoxes = new List<TextBox>();

  //registered for the preinit on the page....
  public void PreInitHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
      {
        var txtBox = new TextBox{Id = textBox+i};
        //...add cell to table and add txtBox Control
        TxtBoxes.Add(txtBox);
      }
  }
}
```